# Access css and html structure of charts [ngx-charts]

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

does anyone know if there is an easy way to manipulate the css and html structure of the graph generated by ngx-chart?

For instance I'd like to be able to move the labels of the x axis from the bottom of the chart to the top.

[my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW8Jo.png)

Any hint would be very appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a way to manipulate css & html of charts as they are based on canvas. But you can customize as per your requirement as given in documentation.

https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/